# WMS with time dimension

Tags: wms, time, dimensions, wms-time

I set up a layer with "time" dimension in GeoServer, but I'm having quite a hard time figuring out how to use it...

It is a vector layer with some polygons in it. This is my layer configuration for Time Dimension:

[image]

Since I set a valid default value, I am able to get that default value simply calling my layer:

http:///geoserver/emodnet/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=emodnet:SatData&styles=&bbox=-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0&width=660&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers&

but I can't possibly figure out how to get the map for different time values!

Also, is it possible to use the 'time' parameter in the WFS too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basically use `TIME=value&` at the end of the WMS request. For a range of values you need to use `TIME=start/end&`. If you look in the GetCapabilities response you will see the values of time that will work.

See this [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html#step-5-query-layer-on-timestamp) for a brief explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, iant! I will try and look in the GetCapabilities to see possible values for my query

Comment: It's working! I was just querying for the wrong values. Thank you again